# There is any possibility to hide a error message when the other error message is displayed?

Tags: html, angularjs

```
 <form name="form">
     <input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="password" name="password" minlength="6"  maxlength="15" ng-pattern="/^\S*$/" required>
     <span ng-show="form.password.$dirty && form.password.$invalid">
       <span ng-show="form.password.$error.required">Password is required.</span>
       <span ng-show="form.password.$error.minlength">Password should have atleast 6 characters.</span>
       <span ng-show="form.password.$error.pattern">White Space not allowed.</span>
     </span>
 </form>
```

In this code if i type less then 6 characters with space it's showing both "Password should have atleast 6 characters." & "White Space not allowed."

I don't want to show both error message's, only one error message should display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to decide which one to show if both conditions are met.

```
<span ng-show="form.password.$error.minlength">Password should have atleast 6 characters.</span>
<span ng-show="form.password.$error.pattern && !form.password.$error.minlength">White Space not allowed.</span>
```

And if you have a third one

```
<span ng-show="form.password.$error.patternQ 
    && !form.password.$error.pattern 
    && !form.password.$error.minlength">Question mark not allowed.</span>
```